# How to feed SQL script to psql from a Java programme?

Tags: java, postgresql, psql

I need to feed a SQL script to a Postgres database. I am creating a `Process` instance that executes `psql` with the script path as argument. The core of the code:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) 
{
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("psql", "-d base", "-U user", "-f path/new_schema.sql");
    Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
    env.put("PGPASSWORD", "pass");
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);

    try
    {
         Process p = pb.start();
         InputStream stdout = p.getInputStream ();
         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(stdout));

         String line;
         while ((line = reader.readLine ()) != null) 
         {
             System.out.println ("Stdout: " + line);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

This way authentication fails with this message:

> psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "user"

Other users [report the same error in other contexts](https://serverfault.com/questions/747238/using-pgpassword-variable-does-not-seem-to-work-any-more-on-postgresql-9-3), apparently Postgres 9.3 no longer uses the `PGPASSWORD` environment variable.

Therefore I tried the alternative route using a `.pgpass` file with these contents:

```
localhost:5432:*:user:pass
```

Then added a new environment variable before launching the `Process` instance:

```
env.put("PGPASSFILE", "/home/user/.pgpass");
```

Still, I receive back the "authentication failed" message.

The `.pgpass` file has the correct permissions (`0600`) and is doing its job if I invoke `psql` directly from the shell.

What am I missing?